# Order of magnetic phase transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, material-science, phase-transition

Is there any phase transition occur in paramagnetism to diamagnetism transitions state. What should be the order and how will I calculate the order?

Comment: A first-order one was claimed to be observed as recently as in 2011: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21661757  And this 2005 paper is also about a first-order one, if I see well: http://kamome.lib.ynu.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/10131/804/1/ISI-000228439600065-01.pdf But I am not familiar with the big picture here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no necessity for there to be a phase transition between paramagnetic and diagmagnetic. They differ only in the sign of a response function, and there is no reason why one coould not continuously deform a paramagnetic material into a diagmagnetic one. As with all properties of materials one could get a discontinuous change in the magnetic response if there is a phase transition, and this is way to detect changes in magnetic order (for example an antiferromagnetic to disordered state). But there is no necessity for a phase transition.

Beware that in some areas the disordered magnetic state is called the "paramagnetic state". This is just an overloading of terminology.